# Xcode 9.2 Coredata issue

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am working on a Swift project where I used Coredata. In Xcode 9.1 project running fine but in Xcode 9.2 I am getting following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aliapple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClaimIt-gvtrxwzmxtcxxtbbbkwqcuqqzvhk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ClaimIt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Claimit.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Claimit/Claimit+CoreDataModel.swift'
```

Complete error screen is displayed in below image. [image]

Here are the settings for xdatamodel inspector

[image][image]

I did Google this problem and found some solutions but nothing worked for me. Here is what I have tried:

1. Cleaned project by command+shift+k
2. Cleaned project by option+shift+command+k
3. Deleted Derived data folder
4. After deleting derived data folder cleaned project again and
   restarted Xcode.
5. In xcdatamodel Inspector selected codegen option to Manual/None and
   Created NsManagedObject subclass manually by
   xcdatamodel->Editor->Create NsManagedObject Subclass. In this case I
   got error on entity that this is undeclared.

I will be very thankful if any one help me to fix this.

Comment: Does your NSPersistentContainer name match that of your xcdatamodel file's name ?

Comment: Yes it does as its working fine in Xcode 9.0.1

Comment: Can you check if that file - Claimit+CoreDataModel.swift is included in Build Phases -> Compile Sources